# Не всплывает модальное окно на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe, youtube

Пытаюсь разобраться с документацией [библиотеки js magnific popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/).

С подраздела `Popup with video or map` беру код и хочу вызвать всплывающее окно с видео на сайте, но окно не появляется.. [фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/4ag465fe/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.popup-youtube, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
    disableOn: 700,
    type: 'iframe',
    mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
    removalDelay: 160,
    preloader: false,

    fixedContentPos: false
  });
});
```

```css
/**
 * Simple fade transition,
 */

.mfp-fade.mfp-bg {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
}
.mfp-fade.mfp-bg.mfp-ready {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.mfp-fade.mfp-bg.mfp-removing {
  opacity: 0;
}
.mfp-fade.mfp-wrap .mfp-content {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
}
.mfp-fade.mfp-wrap.mfp-ready .mfp-content {
  opacity: 1;
}
.mfp-fade.mfp-wrap.mfp-removing .mfp-content {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/master/dist/magnific-popup.css"></script>
<a class="popup-youtube" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0O2aH4XLbto">Open YouTube video</a>
<br>
<a class="popup-vimeo" href="https://vimeo.com/45830194">Open Vimeo video</a>
<br>
<a class="popup-gmaps" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=221B+Baker+Street,+London,+United+Kingdom&amp;hl=en&amp;t=v&amp;hnear=221B+Baker+St,+London+NW1+6XE,+United+Kingdom">Open Google Map</a>
```

Comment: неужели ни у кого нет предположений? странно как-то..

Comment: А что вы ожидаете? Что страницы по ссылкам всплывут как попап?

Comment: @Vartlok да, как на сайте с документацией

Comment: Судя по логам на jsfiddle и на офф сайте, идет обращение на разные адреса и поэтому у вас оно не работает(на jsfiddle приходит опция с запретом на показ в iframe), хотя код одинаковый, почему, я хз.

Comment: @Vartlok вот и я тоже думаю.. еще более странно то, что у некоторых людей работает, притом на хроме и на лисе